# Differentiating Spitzer's identity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk, characteristic-functions

Let $(S_n)$ be an arbitrary random walk. Define $$M_n:= \max(0,S_1,...,S_n)$$ and $$S_n^{+} := \max\{0,S_n\}.$$

Spitzer's identity states that for $0<r<1$, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n E(e^{itM_n}) = \exp \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n} E(e^{itS_n^{+}}) \right) .$$

By differentiating I am supposed to show that

$$E(M_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} E(S_k^{+}). $$

However, differentiating with respect to $t$ and putting $t=0$ gives me

$$(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n E(M_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n} E(S_n^{+}).$$

I cannot see how to get the required result from this.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $a_n:=\mathbb E[M_n]$ and $b_n:=\mathbb E[S_n^+ ]/n$. The LHS is 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^na_n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^na_{n-1}=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n(a_n-a_{n-1}).$$
By identification of the coefficients of power series, we derive that for each $n\geqslant 1$, 
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=b_n,\quad a_0=0,  $$
from which the wanted formula follows.